# I have a issue with trying to convert a number in a text file to an integer

Tags: python

I have a issue with trying to convert a text file to a integer in python, as I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dive\Desktop\Project\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(int(newfile))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.62'
```

and the code below was used to give the error above.

```
with open("previousstockprice.txt", "r") as price:
    for l in price;
       print(sum([int(a) for a in l.split()]))
```

And the text file looks like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV0v6.png)

I also want the output to equal to `.62`, as listed in the text file. This is used to represent the previous stock price.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] so we at least know what the text file looks like.

Comment: The error occured in the line ```print(int(newfile))```, please provide the full code and a sample text file.

Comment: Provide the line that causes the error, say what output you want from that line, and people should be able to tell you how. For example, you might say "the line is `".62"` and I want an output of `8`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float` to cast value:

```
with open("previousstockprice.txt", "r") as price:
    for l in price;
       print(sum([float(a) for a in l.split()]))  # <- float
```

Answer (score 1):

apparently your text file include the number ".62" in it.
and it is a "float" number not an "int"
so you'll get this exception.

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you an exception because you are trying to convert a float to an int. Replace the int() function with a float() and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If a string represents an integer, Python will convert it directly with `int()`. But if it's a string that represent a non-integer number, you have to convert it to a float first, and then you can use `int()` to round it to an integer. For instance, `int(float('.62'))` gives `0` (it rounds down).

Answer (score 0):

A robust way to let the program take care of numeric types in the file:

```
with open("previousstockprice.txt", "r") as price:
    for l in price;
       print(sum(int(a) for a in l.split() if a.isdigit() else round(float(a))))
```

This would also catch negative `int`s since even if they don't fall under `isdigit()` they'll be handled by the other condition.